# Можно ли обратиться к элементу tkinter по имени?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Написал код, создающий в интерфейсе ткинтера поле с введёнными данными (автоматически отступая вниз).

Цель такова: кнопка `Delete` должна удалять созданные вместе с ней элементы интерфейса.

Вопрос: как к конкретным созданным через функцию элементам получить доступ? Пытался через `name` и `id`, не получилось.

P.s перевод введённых данных в поле не работает, т.к. я переписал код и не добавил ещё этого.

```py
Razmer = 0.057

def SozdanieTexta():
    Zadanie = Text(background='white')
    Zadanie.place(relheight=0.2, relwidth=0.25, relx=0.717, rely=Razmer)

def SozdanieZagolovka():
    Zagolovok = ttk.Label(text=Nazvanie.get())
    Zagolovok.place(relheight=0.04, relwidth=0.25, relx=0.717, rely=Razmer-0.04)
    return Zagolovok

def SozdanieKnopkiDelete():
    Delete = ttk.Button(text='X')
    Delete.place(relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.05, relx=0.63, rely=Razmer)

def SozdanieLista():
    global Razmer
    SozdanieTexta()
    SozdanieZagolovka()
    SozdanieKnopkiDelete()
    Razmer += 0.25
    return Razmer
```

Comment: Вероятно, ответ на ваш вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119912/how-do-i-remove-all-elements-in-a-tkinter-gui

Comment: Да, это близко к тому, что мне нужно, команда **root.winfo_children()** в принте выдаёт список всех элементов расположенных в основном окне, однако я не понимаю, как обратиться к элементу в таком формате **<tkinter.Entry object .!entry>**. Допустим, мне нужно его удалить, как это сделать?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что значит: "как обратиться к элементу в таком формате `<tkinter.Entry object .!entry>`"? Как я понял вы просто написали мне тип, который вывелся вам в консоли. По ссылке, которую я кидал, написано же: `child.destroy()`. Или я вас не так понимаю?

Comment: Да, всё верно, это вывод из консоли, если просто написать **print(root.winfo_children())**, сейчас я циклом for перебрал каждый элемент, он выводится в виде **.!text** , **.!entry** и т.д. Допустим, я получил эту информацию и хочу удалить, скажем элемент **.!entry**, конкретно этот элемент, больше никакой. Что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: вот еще ссылка с ответом на эту тему: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384986/accessing-child-widgets-of-a-window-by-their-names Я бы даже сказал, что это дубликат вашего вопроса, просто в английском stackoverflow.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что мне нужно